# Running Tomcat 6 on Win7 as a non-admin

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, tomcat6

I tried to run Tomcat 6 on a Win 7 platform in which I am not an admin.

I got the following:

```
Starting fm_tomcat_default
Asked (and given) winsock 1.1
OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)
```

I can ask admins to change a setting which would allow this app to run, as long as it is just freeing up a finite list of configuration items and not being an admin all the way. But in order to do that, I need to know what to ask them to open up. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I work in a restricted environment too. On my Win7 box, I run Tomcat in a VM using Virtual Box. That gives me full admin rights to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know what to ask them to open up. Any idea?

Ask them to open up **their mind** and grant you admin access to the system. Ok, this is probably not the answer you are looking for, maybe I'm just expressing some past frustrations here.

Comment: yeah, that certainly won't do.  i work at a very large and rigidly structured finaancil corporation.  i understand their policies though.  you have to be rigid when you are that big not not let things go out of control.

Comment: @foampile Right - but if they want you to develop for them, they have to trust you anyway. IMHO you cannot apply the same security policies to both clerks and programmers.